# Detect most up-to-date JavaScript version

Tags: javascript, version

Hey there I'm new to JavaScript and looking for resources to learn it. So far I found a book written in 2001, covering JavaScript Version 1.5 (*JavaScript the definitive guide 4th edition*). 
When looking at Wikipedia the German article claimed that JavaScript 1.8.5. released in 2010 was the latest version. Using (?) *ECMAScript 5 Compliance*. The English article says that ECMAScript 6 released June 17th 2015 is the current stable version and JS 1.8.2 from 2009 is no longer supported, without mentioning newer versions.
Now my question is: What is the actual version of JavaScript right now (October 4th 2015) and how can you find the current version of JavaScript? Or is there even "the one" JavaScript version? Because right now I have a feeling that there are multiple versions.
<s>If you know a good book, blog, ... to learn JavaScript, feel free to leave a comment, since I'm still looking for something to learn it.</s>

Edit: from *JavaScript the definitive guide 4th edition*:

> "JavaScript has evolved over the years, and Netscape has released
>   several versions of the Language. Microsoft has released simular
>   versions [...] under the name "JScript". And ECMA has published [...]
>   JavaScript language under the awkward name "ECMAScript"."

Does that really mean, we're using multiple versions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok, got it... The question remains: Which is the current JavaScript version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the lastest version of Javascript was the 1.8.5

(see the new fatures here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5)

I like to study using the w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), and, If you have some doubts, use the Stackoverflow to satisfy your questions. There's a lot of answers about Javascript here.

I hope this help.